# android app works fine on emulator but crashes on actual device

Tags: android-studio

My android app works fine on emulator but crashes on actual device, i am using socket in my app which is used to receive images and message and works fine on emulator but when I install it on my mobile it receives only messages and on time of receiving image the application crashes, I think it is related to resolution somehow. Image Drawable is v24 in my app. Please guide how can I overcome this issue.